# Querying redshift throws error with a special character when using WHERE clause

Tags: amazon-redshift

Like any other morning, I started my morning by querying redshift. But this time, my queries with `WHERE` clause wouldn't return any results.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT member_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM tablename
WHERE  member_id <> 2
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

and here's the error I get:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT member_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM tablename
WHERE  member_id <> 2
GROUP BY member_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "Â member_id" does not exist in tablename;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.27s
```

In the error description, there's `"Â member_id"`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Any suggestions on how to go about it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE  member_id <> 2
```

You have a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

It looks just like a space, except it's not. It's the space-like character right after the `E` in `WHERE`. Delete that and rerun and it will be happy.

Or you can just copy/paste this:

```
WHERE member_id <> 2
```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much. How did you check for the non breaking spoace character?

Comment: I edited your question so I could get the actual characters set, then I copied those two spaces (which I figured was the issue given the error) and I popped it into a Text-to-Hex website and saw the two byte character code for the nbsp. The most obvious thing was that the hex was 3 bytes (6 hex characters) but there were only two spaces, so it should have only been 2 bytes (4 hex characters).